# Массив в запросе к MySQL. PHP

Tags: php, mysql, массивы

Добрый день! Бьюсь, не могу победить.

Есть чекбокс. Множественный.

```
<form method="post" align="left">

<p><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="a1">a1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="a2" >a2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="a3">a3<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="a4">a4<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="a5">a5связи</p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p><br>
</form>
```

Вот код:

```
if( isset ( $_POST['option'] ) ){
$wtf = $_POST['option'];
$show = implode (",", $wtf);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE event IN (".$show.")";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
```

А дальше сам вывод в виде таблицы.

Так вот - не работает. Причем, если выбрать что-то одно в чек-боксе и подредактировать запрос, типа:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE event LIKE'%".$show."%'";
```

то все выводит.

Содержимое переменной корректно:

```
 var_dump($show);
```

Результат

```
 string(5) "a1,a2"
```

В чем косяк? Как можно еще вывести из базы результат массива? Спасибо всем!

**UPD:** Вывод результата

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 echo "<table class='simple-little-table'><tr><th>ID</th><th>Дата и    время</th><th>№ ключа</th><th>Тип ключа</th><th>Событие</th>  <th>Объект</th><th>Адрес</th><th>Номер договора</th><th>Тип события</th><th>Устройство</th></tr>";
 // Вывод таблиц
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<tr><td>" . $row["id"]. "</td><td>" .$row["datetime"]."</td><td>".$row["numberkey"]."</td><td>".$row["typekey"]."</td><td><b>".$row["event"]."</b></td><td>".$row["name"]. "</td><td>". $row["address"]. "</td><td> " .$row["numberagreement"]."</td><td> ". $row["typeevent"]."</td><td>" .$row["device"]. "</td></tr>";
 }
 echo "</table>";
} else {
 echo "Нет результатов";
}

$conn->close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил опубликовать отдельным ответом, а не комментарием.

Вы, похоже, не совсем понимаете, что происходит и почему.

Строки в базе должны сравниваться со строками, а числа с числами. Когда вы передаете строку в базу для сравнения, она должна быть в кавычках, а когда вы передаете число, оно может быть без кавычек.

Теперь посмотрите на свой запрос. Если вы убираете кавычки, то на выходе получаете запрос типа:

```
select * from `table` where (column in (c4ca4,eccbc,e4da3,8f14e))
```

что вызовет ошибку при выполнении, если умное подключение не поместит условие в кавычки полностью, т.е. не исправит ошибку, получив в итоге опять неправильный запрос

```
select * from `table` where (column in ('c4ca4,eccbc,e4da3,8f14e'))
```

в вашем случае (вы сравниваете строки), вам нужно получить

```
select * from `table` where (column in ('c4ca4','eccbc','e4da3','8f14e'))
```

Но конечный результат все равно не получен, как вы говорите.

Запрос с `(column in ('c4ca4','eccbc','e4da3','8f14e'))` покажет вам ожидаемый набор данных тогда, когда у вас в сравниваемом поле column будут значения **равные** сравниваемым параметрам, т.е. 'c4ca4','eccbc','e4da3','8f14e' . Если у вас такого нет, и в поле column у вас именно текст, в котором нужно проверить существование указанного слова, тогда вам нужен несколько другой запрос, например:

```
select * from `table` where (column like '%c4ca4%') or (column like '%eccbc%') or (column like '%e4da3%') or (column like '%8f14e%')
```

этот запрос, конечно, похож на извращение, но свою задачу выполнит.

Поэтому, вам нужен несколько иной код:

```
if( isset ( $_POST['option'] ) ){
$conditions = [];
foreach ($_POST['option'] as $option) {
$conditions[] = "(event like '%$option%')";
}
$show = implode (" or ", $conditions);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE ".$show;
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
```

Возможно, не самое изящное решение, но в вашем случае должно работать.

Comment: Очень благодарен вам за комментарий. Через час доберусь до рабочей станции и посмотрю, что у нас получилось. Только я не понимаю, что делает строка с запросом к базе. Вы, вероятно, опечатались, а  я теперь не найду разумного объяснения.

Comment: Приведенный вами код не работает. Вообще. localhost отвечает http error 500

Comment: Да, действительно, я забыл поставить ";" в одном месте. С другой стороны, вы можете просто применить разум и посмотреть где и почему возникает эта ошибка в коде.

Comment: я код поправил... вы его проверили? решает он вашу задачу?

Comment: доброе утро!) Нет не работает ваш код. Ошибки 500 нет, но теперь даже не ищет по одиночному результату из чекбокса. Вот содержимое переменной при выборе двух результатов из чекбокса: `string(158) "(even like '%a1%') or (even like '%a2%')"`, а вот из одиночного `string(78) "(even like '%a1%')"`. Я не очень дружу с php и mysql запросами, но мне кажется, что по такому содержимому переменной он ничего и никогда не найдет. Это какой-то замкнутый круг. Вы зря иронизируете насчет "применения разума". Что я только не делал уже. Не работает и хоть убейся об стену.

Comment: Я никак не иронизирую, я констатирую факт. Возможно, я просто ошибся и вместо event написал even... Т.е. вместо строчки `$conditions[] = "(even like '%$option%')";` должна быть `$conditions[] = "(event like '%$option%')";`

Comment: Поправил свой ответ.

Comment: Огромное и человеческое вам спасибо) Все заработало) Даже не представляете, как я вам благодарен!) Вопрос решен!)

Comment: Я рад, что вопрос решен!

Answer (score 2):

Запрос в базу с `IN` должен выглядеть так

```
... IN ('one','two')
```

вам нужно добавить одинарные кавычки

Comment: Спасибо. Кавычки поставил. Стало выводить. Но только по одному любому значению из чек-бокса. $sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE event IN ('".$show."')"; А как бы сделать результат по нескольким пунктам?

Comment: вероятно проблема в коде отображения результата

Comment: я приложил в UPD оставшийся код. Взгляни, если не трудно. Не могу допереть.

Comment: if( isset ( $_POST['option'] ) ){
foreach($_POST['option'] as $option) {
$wtf[] = "'".$option."'";
}
$show = implode (",", $wtf);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE event IN (".$show.")";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

Comment: @stanislav Спасибо за ответ) Правки разумные, но результат тот же. По отдельности выводит, множественно - ни в какую. Единственно, сделал несколько исправлений в вашем коде. `$wtf[] = "'".$option."'"; }` - здесь убрал одинарные кавычки, потому что в этом случае переменной присваивалось значение `string(5) " 'a1,a2' "`, а значит никаких бы совпадений в базе скрипт не нашел. Может, есть еще варианты?(

Comment: покажите текущий sql запрос (то что собственное идёт в базу, а не как конструируется).